# which version of opencv is suitable for android studio 4.0.0?

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I want to integrate android studio with opencv. This is very first android project with opencv and I am not getting exactly which version will be suitable for android studio 4.0.0 so that there will be no any further version related problems I have to face.
Thanks in advance!